# Monitor turns off after a few seconds - both monitors

Tags: display, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, power, dvi

Running into a weird issue - my second monitor started turning off after a few seconds today. I power off and back on, and it immediately powers off again after a few seconds. I tried a spare monitor we have around here and it's now doing the exact same thing after it worked for about 30 min. Tried a spare DVI cable and spare power cable, same thing. Tried plugging it into the DVI connection on the graphics card that the working monitor is plugged into. Same thing. I'm stumped. Unless I just happen to have two dead monitors on hand but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Is there anything common between the outlet you're plugging the monitors into? _Highly unlikely_, but could be an outlet problem.

Comment: I don't think it's a monitor issue at all. It definitely seems to be a graphics card issue, because you used two monitors, spare cables, etc. Did you update the graphic drivers lately? It could be corrupt driver install or the card going bad. You could also try to uninstall the graphics card drivers and use the on-board graphics and see what happens. If it works fine, I'd try reinstalling the drivers for the dedicated card.

Comment: I did try plugging the second monitor into the DVI port that the working monitor was in and had the same issue. I hope it's not the card, it's only a few months old :( I'll explore that, though. 

The monitors are plugged into the same power strip. Tried plugging the non-working one into the wall with no change.

Comment: Sometimes this is a video card driver issue.